# Android Emulator Appears and suddenly disappear

Tags: android-studio, emulation

I try every solution that I get from the Internet but my problem is not solving
[I install HAXM through SDK and it is not asking for updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCHSE.png)

[image]

I didn't get any error message :( I am stuck Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Emulator moved out of the SDK Tools Package in 25.3.1, so the solutions below about specifically adding the Android Emulator package in the SDK Manager in Android Studio 2.3 and higher is the right solution.

Ref. link:~

```
 developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator.html
```

Comment: Thanks this work. But still I am getting some issues when i start emulator it a close window is appear that says:

qemu-system-i386.exe has stop working.

Check online for a solution
Close the program